# WatchKit Extension[31646:1403662] libMobileGestalt utility.c:421: no value found for key 1129072723

Tags: xcode, apple-watch, watchos-6

Does anyone know where to find information about this error from Xcode when running a simulation on the watch

> WatchKit Extension[31646:1403662] libMobileGestalt utility.c:421: no
>   value found for key 1129072723

It happens when I first launch the app every time. 
Im hoping its got nothing to do with my code and something to do with the simulator.

Im currently on Xcode Version 11.1 (11A1027)